# Codeigniter Form Submission Redirect Problems

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Hmm, pulling my hair out a bit here. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but I can't get my form page to submit properly.

At the moment I don't ask it to actually do anything in the model, so I expect when the form is submitted it to redirect elsewhere, or if there is a validation error (or its the first visit to the page) load the form view.

controller:

```
public function edit($page )
  {

  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->helper('html');

  $data['workout'] = $this->workout_model->get_workout($page);
  $data['exercise_list'] = $this->workout_model->get_exercise_list();
  $data['sets'] = $this->workout_model->get_sets($data['workout']['id']);
  $data['scripts'] = array('templates/script_add_ex','templates/script_add_set');

  if(empty($data['workout']))
  {
    show_404();
  }

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('woDate', 'Date', 'required');   //Any way here to just say "no blanks?"

  if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
    $data['title'] = 'Edit Workout - '.$data['workout']['datetime']; 
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('workouts/edit', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
  }
  else
  {
    $woDate = $this->workout_model->update_workout();
    redirect('/workouts/view/'.$woDate);
  }
}
```

Model:

```
public function update_workout()
{
  $woDate = $this->input->post('woDate'); //just simply setting $woDate - is this being returned?
}
```

So I have a view "mysite.com/workouts/view/ with a table of data in it, and a link to "edit" the page, which takes you to "mysite.com/workouts/edit/

When I submit, I expect vaildation rules to be satisfied (woDate is filled in) and to be redirected back to "mysite.com/workouts/view/"

But instead I get sent to "mysite.com/workouts/edit" with no  after "edit", so it throws errors saying that $page is not set, becuase it is not in the URL I guess...But I don't get why it is trying to go back to the edit page when I thought the form submission was valid...

Comment: Your definitely using POST on the form method?

Comment: Try to debug the value of the woDate using die($this->input->post('woDate'));

Comment: where is your <form action=""> pointing to? if it's not set, then it will go back to the same page when you hit submit. have a look at the html source on your edit page.

Comment: In your model, try `return $this->input->post('woDate');`

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 yes.
@Mudshark Same result.
@Loopo I wonder if you are hitting on something there. My form is built such that the output html includes `action="mysite.com/workouts/edit"`. Should it include the current arguement ($woDate)?
Although, having said that, It shouldn't be trying to go to the same page if the form is successful. It should be redirecting to `view`...? Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is all it was...thanks to @Loopo for prompting the thought process.

I opened my form initially with

```
<?php echo form_open('workouts/edit'); ?>
```

Which would result in:

```
<form action="mysite.com/workouts/edit" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Which when validating the form, if it needed to go back to the editing page due to unfulfilled validation, didn't know what to 'edit', so I needed to change it to this:

```
<?php echo form_open('workouts/edit/'.$workout['datetime']); ?>
```

Outputting:

```
<form action="mysite.com/workouts/edit/2014-07-09_12:07" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

This error was preventing things from working properly, so now, on successful form validation, my redirect works.

Thanks all!